# Xcode 4 Developer Info in main.m

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

In Xcode 4, where does the ID information (developer, company) in main.m come from?  On my system it is incorrect, but I can't locate the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer is the user name from user currently logged into Mac OS X and the company can be set in the file inspector when you select the Xcode project in the project navigator.

Answer (score 3):

**To set company/organization**

Click on the Project from Project Navigator(Left side of the screen) >> Targets >> File Inspector (Right side of the screen ) >>  Project Document >> Organization.

[image]

Comment: Easy to understand. Very nice. +1 for it